# What would cause CrystalDiskMark to show different test results for front USB port compared to rear?

Tags: usb, motherboard, usb-3, benchmarking

My motherboard is the Asus B450-i and my case front IO USB ports are plugged into the USB 3.1 Gen 1 header on the motherboard using the cable supplied with the case.  I'm using Windows 11 as my OS.

On the rear I also have 4 additional USB 3.1 Gen 1 ports.  I plugged a USB flash drive into the front to test it's speed, and did the same using a rear port.  These are the results.

I consistently get lower sequential read and write speeds on the front ports.  What could be causing this?

I was thinking it's the cable for the front USB. If I connect an older USB 3.0 extension cable to the rear port, it causes the sequential read/write speeds to drop to the same level as the front ports.

If it is the cable, how can I determine for certain that it is not rated for USB 3.1 Gen 1 speeds? Or does using any cable regardless of speed rating cause a drop in speed?

#### FRONT

[image: FRONT USB PORT]

#### REAR

[image: REAR USB PORT]

**EDIT:** Image of front IO USB ports

[image]
[image]

**EDIT**: Ran USB Device Tree Viewer to check  if my card reader on the front usb port is running at 3.0 speeds and it says that it's not (I'm using a Kingston MobileLite G4 USB 3.0 Memory Card Reader FCR-MLG4 to test)

[image]

Comment: 44MB/s suggests that those ports are USB 2, not USB3.

Comment: @Mokubai that was my suspicion.  So does that mean the front IO cable that came with my case is actually rated for only USB 2 even though it connects to the USB 3.1 Gen 1 slot on the motherboard?

Comment: @erotavlas - What’s your case?

Comment: @Ramhound NCase M1 Classic https://ncased.com/products/m1-classic

Comment: USB 2 cables and USB 3 cables have different physical layout, 4 data lines vs. 8. See https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-bcaed5458e66b8c0a3e47dab2bca5fea . You can use USB 2 devices and cables on USB 3 port, but get slower throughput. See how many data lines go into the ports -- though USB 3 should have blue insulator, not all do.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I added picture of the ports.  It looks like they have the extra data lanes.

Comment: Did you even look at the specs for the [Asus B450-i](https://rog.asus.com/us/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-b450-i-gaming-model/spec/)? It clearly states: “2 x USB 2.0 port(s) (2 at mid-board) / 2 x USB 3.1 Gen 1 port(s) (2 at mid-board)” So my guess is your front panel ports are connecting to the mid-board connectors.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 my front panel ports are connected to the correct board connector - if you look at the motherboard diagram, there is only two connectors, one for USB 2 (10 pin) and one for USB 3 (20pin)  it is impossible to plug my front IO USB cable into the board connector for USB 2 because it will not fit (has 20 pin connector, not 10 pin)

Comment: @erotavlas Fair enough.